# Check for the longest continuous sequence where the previous number is a divisor of the current number

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

How could my current code that reads integers until -1 is input and checks for the longest pattern of even/odd/even be modified to check for the longest continuous sequence where the previous number is a divisor of the current number.

Code:

```
longest=[]
current=[]

while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == -1:
        break

    if current and current[-1] % 2 != n % 2:
        current.append(n)
    else:
        current = [n]

    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current

print(len(longest))
```

Closest attempt:
Code:

```
longest=[]
current=[]

while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == -1:
        break

    if current % current[-1] == 0:
        current.append(n)
    else:
        current = [n]

    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current

print(len(longest))
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `current[-1]` is the previous number, you can simply change:

```
if current and current[-1] % 2 != n % 2:
```

to:

```
if current and n % current[-1] == 0:
```

Sample input:

```
1
2
4
8
2
4
-1
```

would output:

```
4
```